# What happens first, implicit conversion to return value or destruction of local variable?

Tags: c++

I just bumped into code like the following which looks fishy to me (details left out to protect the innocent):

```
std::string MakeString()
{
    char buf[12] = { 0 };
    return &buf[0];
}
```

Is this OK or unsafe? Is it guaranteed that std::string is created before buf goes out of scope?

Comment: You should return non-POD objects as const whenever you can. `const std::string MakeString()`

Comment: @qdii: no, you shouldn't. It prevents moving from them.

Comment: @qdii Not anymore. In C++11, returning types as `const` is generally a bad idea, because of move constructors (which cannot move from a `const` rvalue).

Comment: `std::string` will be created with constructor (const char*) since `char*` is passed.

Comment: How could the destruction of the local variable possibly *precede* its conversion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have written is equivalent to:

```
std::string MakeString()
{
    char buf[12] = { 0 };
    return buf;
}
```

And it is always guaranteed that this code is safe. In fact this case is not much different from any function that returns a value by copy.